# Populate html markup with data from the database

Tags: php, html, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to translate between php and ASP.Net. In php I can connect to the database, run a query, and print out the results in html tags as shown below:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM comments;";

$result=$mysqli->query($query);

while($row=$result->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<div class=\"comment\">";
    echo "<h1>".$row->title."</h1>";
    echo "<p>".$row->comment."</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

?>

In ASP.NET with c#, how would I do this?

I'm aware I have to use SqlConnection() and SqlCommand() and possibly SqlDataReader(). But how do I make ASP.NET do what I have php doing above? And where do I place the code? In the Page Load method? Or in the middle of the html?

I have looked a using grid views and table views to pull data from the database, however they don't allow me to make the page look how I want. I want data from the database to populate a html template I mark up, not some predefined grid or table structure.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on the flavor of ASP.Net you want to use, [this reference on working with data in WebPages/Razor](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data) via Visual Studio or [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) tools should be extremely helpful. Hth...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do all of this in sql-server as well. see below ....

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Comments TABLE(Title NVARCHAR(100), Comment NVARCHAR(4000))
INSERT INTO @Comments VALUES
('Title 1', 'Comments for under tile 1'),
('Title 2', 'Comments for under tile 2'),
('Title 3', 'Comments for under tile 3')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 'comment'  AS [@class] 
       ,Title     AS [h1]
       ,Comment   AS [p]
FROM @Comments
FOR XML PATH('div');
```

**Result**

```
<div class="comment">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <p>Comments for under tile 1</p>
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <p>Comments for under tile 2</p>
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <h1>Title 3</h1>
  <p>Comments for under tile 3</p>
</div>
```